# First group of non-zero values (by neglecting single occurrence of zero)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is what I intend to do in Python:

I have an array (`freq_arr`). I want to find the indices of the first group of non-zero elements. I start searching for non-zero elements from start, when I find the first non-zero element (the first element is 5, in the example below), I record its index (4, in the example shown below). I search for the next one, and record its index (which will be 5). If I encounter a single zero, I want to neglect it and continue searching for non-zero values. This way, I consider the values 5,6,0,8,9,0,1 with indices 4,5,6,7,8,9 and 10. After these values, there are five zeros and hence I stop my search. Upto a maximum of *two zeros* can exist in the output, and search continues. However, if I encounter 3 or more zeros, I want to stop searching.

Input:

```
freq_arr = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 8, 9, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 0])
```

Output:

```
out_arr_indices = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I know to code this using for loops, but I want to avoid it since it's not efficient. Kindly let me know how this can be done.

The array will be single dimension. Each element will be in the range of 5000 to 20000.

Comment: For operations like this with a lot of counting and exceptions, I'd recommend looking into `@jit` from the `numba` package.  Write out your loopy code and give it a `@jit` decorator and you'll often be nearly as fast, with clearer code, as a vectorzed solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach with slicing and argmax (to detect non-zeros and zeros) -

```
def start_stop_indices(freq_arr, W=3):
    nnz_mask = freq_arr!=0
    start_idx = nnz_mask.argmax()
    m0 = nnz_mask[start_idx:]
    kernel = np.ones(W,dtype=int)
    last_idx = np.convolve(m0, kernel).argmin() + start_idx - W
    return start_idx, last_idx
```

Sample runs -

```
In [203]: freq_arr
Out[203]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 8, 9, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 0])

In [204]: start_stop_indices(freq_arr, W=3)
Out[204]: (4, 10)

In [205]: start_stop_indices(freq_arr, W=2)
Out[205]: (4, 10)

In [206]: start_stop_indices(freq_arr, W=1)
Out[206]: (4, 5)
```

Here's another for the fixed window search of length = `3`, avoiding the use of `convolution` and making more use of `slicing` -

```
def start_stop_indices_v2(freq_arr):
    nnz_mask = freq_arr!=0
    start_idx = nnz_mask.argmax()
    m0 = nnz_mask[start_idx:]
    idx0 = (m0[:-2] | m0[1:-1] | m0[2:]).argmin()
    last_idx = idx0 + start_idx - 1
    return  start_idx, last_idx
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems like an efficient (and clever) way, making no use of loops. Does it have any advantage (in terms of speed/memory) over @rickjerrity's answer?

Comment: @Meghana Well if that non-zero island is very close to the beginning and the non-zero island is of short length, you might see the loopy one faster, but for generic cases, I would think this would be more efficient. I would advise testing it out at your end to see how these two perform.

Comment: Thanks! What is the difference between the two approaches you mentioned? Again, in terms of speed? Does convolution (first snippet) require higher resources?

Comment: @Meghana Well convolution method would make more sense when you have that `W` is a bigger number. The second method also avoids the negation of mask. So, I am guessing for `W=3`, the second one would be more efficient.

Comment: Okay, that sounds good. Can the `W` be generalized in second snippet as well? (Value of `idx0`)

Comment: @Meghana Thanks for the inspiration. Updated the first one to avoid the negation. The second method would make sense only for small W, so kept it that way. For generic W, the second method would need a loop, so not tinkering there.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem right, you want to iterate through the list skipping two zeros or less in a row, and add the indices of non-zero values to an output array. Maybe something like below

```
freq_arr = [0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 8, 9, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 0]
outputarr = []

count = 0
zerocount = 0

while count < len(freq_arr) and zerocount < 3:
    if freq_arr[count] == 0:
        zerocount += 1
    else:
        zerocount = 0
        outputarr.append(count)
    count += 1
```

If you provide more details we might be able to assist better.

Comment: Thanks! My code was similar to this, instead I used a for loop instead of while. However, my freq_arr will have around 700000 elements. Is it still advisable to use this code snippet?